# How to disable transparency only on the Menu Bar?

Tags: menu-bar, sonoma

Now with macOS Sonoma this issue is more visible. The menu bar is extremely ugly and misplaced depending on the background on the system, as example:

[image: Horrible menu bar color]

It's barely visible and it does not compose with the OS.

All the options available on the system disable transparency entirely on the OS and that isn't the solution.

I tried using third party softwares like Bartender to set it pitch black bit it does not work either.

Suggestions?

PS: This isn't a duplicate, other topics does not address the issue on this question:

- [Mojave: possible to disable menubar transparency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341705/mojave-possible-to-disable-menubar-transparency)
- [How to change macOS Mojave’s menu bar transparency](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368473/how-to-change-macos-mojave-s-menu-bar-transparency)
- [How to get dark menu bar and dock in Mojave light mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337478/how-to-get-dark-menu-bar-and-dock-in-mojave-light-mode)
- [macOS enable reduce transparency option except for dock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423174/macos-enable-reduce-transparency-option-except-for-dock)

Comment: Put appropriately colored bar in wallpaper image behind menu bar.  Set wallpaper image.  Done.

Comment: I agree that the "Reduce Transparency" answer in [Mojave: possible to disable menubar transparency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341705/mojave-possible-to-disable-menubar-transparency) is unsatisfactory, but I don't think it warrants a new question. Both this and the linked question are really asking the same thing. We just don't have a good answer.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the issue which is not addressed by the older questions? At first glance they look rather similar.